# Does TinyTDS support Ruby 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.0, tiny-tds

I am having real trouble trying to get TinyTDS working with Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows 7.

When i run a `rails c` (or `require tiny_tds` from an `irb`), i get the following:

```
D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- tiny_tds/tiny_tds (LoadError)
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
            from S:/code/user/app/ruby2_test/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
            from D:/Ruby/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
            from script/rails:6:in `require'
            from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have tried installing the latest version of the gem:

`gem install tiny_tds --pre`

And looking inside:

`D:\Ruby\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\tiny_tds-0.6.0.rc1-x86-mingw32\lib\tiny_tds`

I can see there is no `2.0` directory, which leads me to believe version 2.0 isn't supported. However i can see no mention on the TinyTDS github or any other sites about this issue.

So, am i missing something or does TinyTDS currently just not work with Ruby 2.0?

Comment: Windows 7, x64. Sorry will update question

Comment: Can you try uninstalling the `gem uninstall tiny_tds` and then re-installing with `gem install tiny_tds --platform=ruby`

Comment: Also from the following GitHub issue: https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/110. MetaSkills he states `Windows users, we are going to have to wait for rake-compiler to be solved.` So I believe this is a dependency issue with Windows I am afraid.

Comment: `gem install tiny_tds --platform=ruby` gives a `libiconv is missing` error. With regards to rake-complier - what is it? `bundle show rake-compiler` gives `Could not find gem 'rake-compiler'`

Comment: I believe this is an issue with OS that you are using as another individual had the same issue. As stated I believe this is a dependency issue with Windows. Please see the comment from `MetaSkills` - https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/110#issuecomment-15503928

Comment: @David - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn you copying the answer from the comments above is fine by me. So long as the solution is there for others. All good by me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> I believe this is an issue with OS that you are using as another
>   individual had the same issue. As stated I believe this is a
>   dependency issue with Windows. Please see the comment from MetaSkills
>   - https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/110#issuecomment-15503928

~ answer per [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529640/david)